# How to sort and group tuple into CSV to return averages and sum values in Python

Tags: python, csv

I have the following code:

```
def write_data2(data_in, data_out):
    out = []
    for team, group in groupby(data_in, lambda x: x.Team):
        group = list(group)
        d2 = {}
        d2['Team'] = team
        d2['Points'] = sum(int(i.Points) for i in group)
        d2['AvgPoints'] = ((int(Points))/(int(NumOfRider)) # change code here
        d2['NumOfRider'] = sum(int(i.NumOfRider) for i in group)
        out.append(d2)
        with open(data_out, 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
            fieldnames = ['Team', 'Points', 'AvgPoints', 'NumOfRider']
            writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
            writer.writeheader()
            for row in out:
                writer.writerow(row)
```

To sort the following namedtuple:

```
[FinalClubResults(Team='Team 1', Points='23', AvgPoints='11.5', NumOfRider='2'), FinalClubResults(Team='Team 1', Points='21', AvgPoints='21', NumOfRider='1'), FinalClubResults(Team='Team 2', Points='12', AvgPoints='12', NumOfRider='1')]
```

into this format:

```
Team,Points,AvgPoints,NumOfRider
Team1,44,14.6667,3
Team2,12,12,1
```

I need some assistance in how to define `'AvgPoints'`, the code so far returns:

```
d2['AvgPoints'] = ((int(Points))/(int(NumOfRider)))
    NameError: name 'Points' is not defined`
```

I would also appreciate if you could look at how the other values are determined to see if they are likely to cause errors or get the incorrect value.

I should also say I need to stick to built in libaries.

Comment: [`statististics.mean()`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/statistics.html#statistics.mean) is builtin library. `d2['AvgPoints'] = mean(int(i.Points) for i in group)`

Comment: @AndrejKesely - I tried this and it returns `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Points'`, if I try `mean(float(i.Points) for i in group)` it returns `ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Points'`. The values are a mix of decimal values and integers. But, I am confused as to why neither `float` or `int` work.

Comment: That means you have string `'Points'` in place of number in your data. You probably read the header alongside your data rows. When you read your data, skip the header.

Comment: @AndrejKesely, thanks got it solved that problem. However, I remember the reason I used `((int(Points))/(int(NumOfRider)))` is because the mean of the AvgPoints is not necessarily the mean of the Points. For example, the first Team 1 in the list has 2 riders and their total points is 10, the next Team 1 is just 1 rider and has 10 points. Therefore, based on `mean(int(i.Points) for i in group)` will return `10`, but I want it to return `6.66667` as there are 20 points and 3 riders is this possible?

Comment: solved not the cleanest way but:

`(sum(float(i.Points) for i in group))/(sum(int(i.NumOfRider) for i in group))`